# Cache a view in Angular JS 1.4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

How do I cache a view in Angualr JS 1.4. I have a main view and a detail view. When I go back to my main view it reloads the view and controller each time. I have a long scrolling list view and want to be able to return to the view from a detail page without it reloading all my data and having to scroll all the way back down to my last position.

Thanks,

RGecy

Comment: Thanks for the vote down! If the question and research was so easy, show me where and how to do it! Have looked for days on the subject! I wouldn't be asking otherwise!

Comment: You probably have been voted down mostly because there's no code to show that you tried something and that can help us to give you some hint. Please, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: cache the state of the view model, not the view itself. If using `ui-router` it has ability to do this but can also do it yourself in a service

Comment: Ok, so I was looking at this also since I have used Ionic and it will cache the view model. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is actually conflating two different concepts.  Out of the box angular supports, template caching.  So if you're controller requests /scripts/myDirective.html, it will only make that network request once.

However, angular is not caching the the template and not the interpolated values that is rendered to the DOM. So:

```
<div>Hello, {{name}}</div>
```

is cached, but

```
<div> Hello John </div>
```

is not, since name is dependent on the app state and can change.

My recommendation would be to cache the results of the network call that retrieves the data (the angular [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) client supports this and then, when returning to the main controller, pass a parameter to indicate where in the list a user should be looking.

Comment: Thank you! This is what I have been seeing as well. So according to this, there is no way to cache a view in the DOM? say like Ionic does?

Comment: So you could write a custom implementation of ui-vew to handle this, but that would probably be a last resort for handling really old and slow machines.  Ionic does it since it has to support a very large variety of hardware